# Are integrally closed domains Dedekind domains?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, dedekind-domain

A domain $D$ is *integrally closed* if it is integrally closed in its field of fractions $F$. A Noetherian ring may not be integrally closed; for example, $\mathbf{Z}\sqrt{5}$ is Noetherian but it is not integrally closed in its field of fractions $\mathbf{Q}\sqrt{5}$.

> It is said that every Dedekind domain is integrally closed. Does the converse hold, namely are integrally closed domains Dedekind Domains?

The only example of an integrally closed domain that I have is the ring of integers and the examples of a Dedekind domain are PID and the ring of integers of a number field. May you please provide an example of an integrally closed domain which is not Dedekind?

Would you help me, please? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is your definition of Dedekind domain? Because my definition answers this question immediately.

Comment: @Arthur A domain $D$ is called a Dedekind domain if every D-fractional ideal of $F$ is invertible.

Answer (score 5):

No. Among many characterisations, Dedekind domains are noetherian integrally closed domains of Krull dimension $1$, i.e. every non-zero  prime ideal is maximal.

As a simple counter example, if $K$ is a field, the ring of polynomials $K[X_1,\dots, X_n]$ is a noetherian integral domain of Krull dimension $n$.

Furthermore, a valuation domain of dimension (height) $1$ is integrally closed (as all valuation domains), but it is not necessarily a Dedekind domain, as it is not necessarily a *discrete* valuation domain.

Answer (score 2):

There are many characteristic properties of Dedekind domains: on the order of ten are given in Chapter 20 [of these notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/integral2015.pdf): see especially Theorem 20.10.  Various texts take several of these properties to be the definition, but probably the most standard definition (and the one taken in my notes is)

> A Dedekind domain is a Noetherian integrally closed domain of Krull dimension at most one (i.e., nonzero prime ideals are maximal).

In my opinion this is the most immediately perspicuous definition: in practice, when you meet a domain it is easier to see whether these properties hold than e.g. whether all fractional ideals are invertible.  To show the latter property *by hand* in any domain that is not a PID is not so easy.

Notice that this definition strongly suggests an answer to your question: if every integrally closed domain were also Noetherian and of Krull dimension at most one, then why include these two other properties in the definition?

It is an amusing exercise to show that these three properties are completely independent, i.e., all eight possibilities arise.  Let's look at the four cases that are integrally closed.

1. $\mathbb{Z}$ is integrally closed, Noetherian and of Krull dimension one.
2. $\mathbb{Z}[t]$ is integrally closed, Noetherian and of Krull dimension two.
3. A valuation ring with value group $(\mathbb{Q},+)$ is integrally closed, non-Noetherian and of Krull dimension one.
4. $\mathbb{Z}[t_1,t_2,\ldots,t_n,\ldots]$ is integrally closed, non-Noetherian and of infinite Krull dimension.

Notice that examples 1), 2) and 4) are all UFDs, but example 3) is not.  In fact a UFD of Krull dimension at most one is not only Noetherian but a PID: see e.g.
Corollary 15.2 from [the same notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/integral2015.pdf).

Comment: 2) is a UFD because $\mathbb Z$ is a UFD

Comment: @cat: Thanks.  My mistake was in the numbering: I had switched 2) and 3) in my mind.